# Disable all extensions on localhost in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to **disable all the extensions** I have installed in **Google Chrome v26 only for** `http://localhost/`?

The reason is, some of the extensions inject HTML and load images into the page, like Feedly and Readability, which I don't want to see when I testing pages.

Comment: Different answer, but I use [Chrome Profiles](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) for this. I have my "Normal" profile, then a dev profile with no extensions, and just switch between the two. I haven't been able to find exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Not a bad idea! I'll use it till I find any other better solution! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 10):

@vcsjones commented that you can use [Chrome Profiles](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) to accomplish this. It's not disabling extensions, rather it's creating a separate profile which will load a different extension manifest.

Great idea. Just wished he posted it as an answer instead.

What you can do with this separate profile is download extensions you need exclusively for dev: Postman, React Dev Tools, etc.

Answer (score 2):

ironically, there is an extension for that, it disables all extensions with one click
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/niemebbfnfbjfojajlmnbiikmcpjkkja

Comment: This disables *all* extensions, not just the ones affecting localhost. Besides, the extension is ancient and will soon stop to work because it still uses manifest v1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also switch person by clicking the you username near minimize button and browse as guest. There, the default chrome without extension is served